# changing my JSON data when submitting form

Tags: json, angular, forms

at the moment when I submit my order form the JSON looks like this:

```
{
"QTY": "x",
"ID": "xxx",
"cart_type": "xxx"
}
```

However I need it to look like the following:

```
{
 data:{
  "QTY": "x",
  "ID": "xxx",
  "cart_type": "xxx"
  }
}
```

my ts file looks like this:

```
onAddtoCart(newOrder) {
    console.log(newOrder);
    this.loading = true;
    this.mhttp.addToCart()
    .subscribe((cart: any) => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.saveCartRef(cart.cartRef);
      console.log(newOrder);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `newOrder` in a JS object like this:

```
onAddtoCart(newOrder) {
    const wrappedNewOrder = {data: newOrder}
    // then the rest as before but using wrappedNewOrder
}
```